# How to make an element don't widen to the size of its content and stay in width of its inline-block parent with variable width?

Tags: css

Imagine a structure:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">Variable, but Desired Width</div>
    <div class="second">Text that may be long. But it should not exceed the width of the element above.</div>
</div>
```

---

I am looking for a **pure CSS** solution (if it is possible) to the following:

- `.first` is inline-block and its width may vary depending on its content.
- I want `.second` to take the full width of `.first`, and **do not exceed it**.

---

*A picture is worth a thousand words:*

[image]

Comment: Not possible without JS. It would mean `.container` should both expand when its children need it (`inline` behavior requested for `.first`) and stop its children from growing and make them wrap (`block` behavior requested for `.second`). You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Are you able to change your html markup or it shall to be like the example?

Comment: @Adriano, yes markup can be changed. The idea is to get second element's width equal to the first that is inline-block.